# How much storage can windows 8.1 support?

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, windows-8.1

How much internal storage can windows 8.1 support? I've been looking to upgrade to a 6TB hard-drive disk. more specifically: [http://www.amazon.com/HGST-Western-Digital-Company-0S03839/dp/B00O0M5QK8/ref=pd_rhf_gw_s_cp_6_KAE1?ie=UTF8&refRID=1F187W46D1MT2F528QM8](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00O0M5QK8)

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically Windows supports up to **9.4 ZB** (9.4 zettabytes, or 9.4 billion terabytes).

So a 6 TB hard drive will be fine.

For more info check: http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/2581408

Answer (score 0):

64 bit Windows 8 can use the GPT (GUID Partition Table) format for the disk, along with the an EFI/UEFI BIOS to boot off of said disk.

Accoring to this link on [GPT VS MBR](http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/how-to/storage/3539201/gpt-vs-mbr-which-hard-drive-format-for-windows-81/), GPT theoretically allows for a maximum size of **9.4ZB** (9.4 billion TB), *however Windows currently limits GPT partitions to **256TB.***